# No matching distribution found for numpy (from torch==1.10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

Working on Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM.

I have python3 installed at /usr/bin/python3.6 according to `whereis python3`.
When I run `pip3 freeze`, I see `numpy` installed, with version `1.15.4`, and when I enter into `python3` console, I can `import numpy as np` perfectly fine with no errors.

What I am trying to do now is to install PyTorch, specifically `torch==1.1.0`, without GPU / CUDA.
I got the following installation instructions from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/:

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I downloaded these wheel files, and tried to run them from local directory as such:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install ~/Desktop/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

and got the following error:

```
No matching distribution found for numpy (from torch==1.1.0)
```

I don't understand why this is the case, cause my `numpy` library is clearly already installed and working (READ ABOVE: I am able to import `numpy` in `python3` console). Also, I had no issues installing PyTorch with GPU on my Windows machine, with `torch 1.1.0` and `numpy 1.15.4`.

Alternatively, I tried to build PyTorch from source by moving into the PyTorch source directory and executing `/usr/bin/python3 setup.py install`, but it didn't work since I am not using a GPU, and CUDA is not installed. I am not able to find instructions on how I can build PyTorch from source without GPU in a Linux environment?

Can anyone kindly advise? Thank you!

Some additional information
(1) Tried to install `PyTorch` with the `--no-dependencies` flag as suggested by @Jan, and it installed, but I am not sure if `Torch` will really work perfectly.
(2) `which pip3` points to `/usr/bin/pip3`
(3) `pip3 show numpy` tells me that the location is at `/home/name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Comment: If you are sure that all dependencies are manually installed, you could try `--no-dependencies` flag for `pip3`. Otherwise, I would point you to Anaconda as python environment provider, it is pretty convenient.

Comment: Hi, it managed to install with the `--no-dependencies` flag, but I am not sure if it was really properly installed. Can you advise on how I may be able to test this? @Jan

Comment: `python -c "import torch"` would be a good starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already. It imported fine. @Jan

Comment: Well you may want to go ahead and run a simple tutorial from the pytorch website then. I'd still recommend you to take a look at Anaconda, it makes a lot of things easier.

Comment: Actually, it's okay, I think everything is working fine. I had existing code running BERT on PyTorch that I wrote some time ago, and I tested using that. Everything's working fine. Thanks for the help! If you would like to post your first comment as a reply, I would select it as my answer. I kept mistakenly thinking that `--no-index` would do the job instead of `--no-dependecies`, no idea why. Talk about major brain fart. Once again, thank you for the pointer! @Jan

Comment: Done so, maybe it'll help someone else as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that all dependencies are manually installed, you could try `--no-dependencies` flag for `pip3`. Otherwise, I would point you to Anaconda as python environment provider, it is pretty convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Since it would seem that `pip` works correctly, you could try creating a virtual environment using [venv](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) and install things from there.

I tested it on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04) and I installed `torch` successfully without CUDA by launching the same commands that you used, but in the `virtualenv`.
Just make sure that once you activate the environment, `which python` and `which pip` point to those in the env (i.e NOT `/usr/bin/`, but most likely in `/home/<user>/<venv_name>/bin/python`).

**Edit:**
Here are the steps I followed:
1) Install `virtualenv` with:

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

2) create a virtualenv named `nogpu-venv` (or whatever) with:

```
python3 -m venv nogpu-venv
```

This will create a folder where you launched the command named `nogpu-venv`.
3) Then activate the `venv` with `source nogpu-venv/bin/activate`. 
You should see `(nogpu-venv)` to the left of your name in the terminal. Also, the commands `which python` and `which pip` should point to the respective files in the `nogpu-venv`.
4) Install `torch` with:

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.3.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, do you think that you can give me a more detailed step-by-step reply as to how you successfully installed `Torch` on your machine? Just to be clear, I am trying to install `Torch` on a VM, :/ Thank you!